# Is it possible to limit the search query to show australia only in google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have currently used this code.

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'}
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

It works great on filtering the Australian suburb / postcodes. But when user search only with post code it shows "Europe".

I would like to limit the search within Australia... Any help ?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of which "Europe" is shown when you type post code?

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply unfortunately I couldn't upload image here.search will be look like the following... step1: user enter only post code (ex: 2500) in the text box (note: User wont choose the predictive listed @ pac-container ). They just hit enter and it should show the locations appropriate within Australia.

Comment: There must be another issue in your rest of code. I embedded your shared code to Google's example code and tried with it and no problem was occured. By the way, are you trying to filter search results or filter autocomplete results?

Comment: Yes the code does its function in correct way... I think I was looking for additional one...   can you check this --> user enter only post code (ex: 2500) in the text box (note: User wont choose the predictive listed @ pac-container ). They just hit enter and it should show the locations appropriate within Australia.

Answer (score -1):

This function should do it for you. It will allow you to search by postal code and address as well.

```
function showAddress(address,countryCode)
{
    geocoder=newGClientGeocoder();
    if(geocoder)
    {
        geocoder.setBaseCountryCode(countryCode); //Set this to"Au"
        geocoder.getLatLng(address,
        function(point)
        {
            if(!point)
            {
                alert(address+"notfound");
            }
            else
            {
                if(addressMarker)
                {
                    map.removeOverlay(addressMarker);
                }
                addressMarker=newGMarker(point);
                map.setCenter(point);
                map.addOverlay(addressMarker);
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is about autocomplete feature, not about geocoding. Also, `GClientGeocode()` is v2 object which is no longer available.

Comment: In that case you can set the bounds in your options. Set the bounds to to LatLngBounds.